# Множество меток и геокодирование в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите как в API яндекс карт задать много меток через геокодирование?
Т.е. как здесь https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager только через геокодирование

Answer (score 0):

Можно изначально добавить в свойства объектов их адреса, и, последовательно их геокодируя, добавлять координаты в их геометрию. Начальные координаты при этом можно либо указать произвольные, либо вообще опустить.

```
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redDotIcon');
objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueClusterIcons');

data.features.forEach(function (obj) {
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(obj.properties.address);
    myGeocoder.then(function(res) {
        var newCoords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
        obj.geometry.coordinates = newCoords
                objectManager.add(obj);
    });
});
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
```

Наглядно, но без аякса: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/veqj7xzc/